# Setting Log file path in app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config

I have one requirement that i have to place the log file in the same directory of solution. That is my solution is placed in [drive]\work\Project1\solution file. But i have to create my log file to [drive]\work\Project1\Log\log.log. How it can be set in app.config file.
please help me. thanks in advance...

Comment: What logging technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume the Visual Studio directory layout, then your program will be in [drive]\work\Project1\bin\Release\ (or possibly \Debug).  And you want your log file to be in the directory [drive]\work\Project1\Log.

That directory is the same as `[drive]\work\Project1\bin\Release\..\..\Log\`

So, one way to do it would be to get the executing program's full path name, extract the directory, and append ....\Log.  Like this:

```
using System.IO; // for Path class
using System.Windows.Forms;  // for Application.ExecutablePath

...

string GetLogFilePath()
{
    string ProgramPath = Path.GetDirectory(Application.ExecutablePath);
    string LogPath = Path.Combine(ProgramPath, @"\..\..\Log\");
    return LogPath;
}
```

If you don't want to include System.Windows.Forms, you can instead include System.Reflection and get the assembly's location with Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.